# receive post data and parse to json?

Tags: arrays, text

i have a small script that call an .php file on background, this php file make an echo with jason and i will receive it with js...

```
$.post("processing/contentloader.php", { process: 'moreContent', route: 'myRoute') }, function(data)
{
    var $data = $.parseJSON( data ); // value of data = {"status":"true","elems":"3","items":"string here"}
    console.log( $data );

// or other Test
var newData = {};
    newData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log( newData );
});
```

When i print data i receive this form php file: "{"status":"true","elems":"3","items":"string here"}" but my js accept this not and build not an array of this Jason string =(

Comment: What it is printing on JS side. When you are doing console.log($data)?

Comment: Check console is this giving any error?

Comment: at print data as string and not as array or with the other test i become Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i

Comment: Ahh okay, the .php file print incorrect json string, now work its!